# How to get data from angular js ng-if condition inside input box

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get data in angular js controller using angularjs form submission  `ng-submit="method"`

Normally all data I can see in controller using `alert()`. Now the problem is if I use `ng-if`  condition inside of angular form then this specific field value show `undefined`. How can I solve this?

```
<div class="row" id="BarcodeDiv">

    <span ng-model="br" ng-init="br=1" id="br" style="display:none;"><i class="fa fa-etsy" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>

    <span ng-if="br==2">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>Serial Number</label>  <span ng-click="barCodeChanger()"  style="cursor:pointer;"><i class="icon-rotate-cw3"></i></i></span>
    <input type="text" name="Barcode" ng-model="Barcode1" class="form-control" placeholder="123">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <label>From</label>
    <input type="text" name="StartFrom" ng-model="StartFrom" id="StartFrom" class="form-control" placeholder="4" style="padding:5px;">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <label>To</label>
    <input type="text" name="ToEnd" ng-model="ToEnd" id="ToEnd" class="form-control" placeholder="9" style="padding:5px;">
</div>
</span>
<span ng-if="br==1">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <label>Serial Number</label> <span ng-click="barCodeChanger()" style="cursor:pointer;"><i class="icon-rotate-ccw3"></i></span>
<input type="text" name="Barcode" ng-model="Barcode" class="form-control" placeholder="123">
</div>
</span>

</div>
```

Comment: Don't bind to attributes of the scope. Bind to attributes of an object which is on the scope. ng-if defines its own scope. Also, don't use ng-init. Initialize values from the controller code.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `ng-if` is scope `true` so the vars won't necessarily show in your controller.  Try replacing `ng-if` with `ng-show`.  You should see the values.

However, `ng-if` is more efficient than `ng-show`.
Another option would be to create object in your controller let's say `$scope.submitData = {}` and bind `Barcode1`, ... via this object.  So in your controller you would have to initialize `$scope.submitData = {}' and in the view you would reference it as

`ng-model='submitData.Button1`

Comment: I create the object but result same. ng-show does not fulfill my requirement